# Using Eval in a GridView for a DropDownList Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, drop-down-menu, eval

Right now, I have a database field named 'PROCESS_FLAG' that contains the text value (A, I, E, C) and I want to be able to change the default selected value of my dropdownlist column depending on the value of PROCESS_FLAG and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is the code for the GridView that I have:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="REQUESTQTY" HeaderText="Request Quantity" 
                SortExpression="REQUESTQTY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MOVEFROM" HeaderText="Move From" 
                SortExpression="MOVEFROM" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MOVETO" HeaderText="Move To" 
                SortExpression="MOVETO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COMPLETEDBY" HeaderText="Completed By" 
                SortExpression="COMPLETEDBY" Visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COMPLETION_DATE" HeaderText="Completion Date" 
                SortExpression="COMPLETION_DATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COMMENTS" HeaderText="Comments" 
                SortExpression="COMMENTS" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RESPONSETIME" HeaderText="Response Time" 
                SortExpression="RESPONSETIME" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_FLAG" HeaderText="Process Flag"
                SortExpression="PROCESS_FLAG" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UNIQUEKEY" HeaderText="Unique Key"
                SortExpression="UNIQUEKEY" Visible="true" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send To...">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StatusDD_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="A">Active</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="C">Complete</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="I">In Process</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="E">Error</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to set the default selected value of the drop down list depending on the value of PROCESS_FLAG.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I am not a pro at all with the Eval function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a OnRowDataBound attribute to the gridview in the .aspx page:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="id" OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler">
```

Then, replace

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_FLAG" HeaderText="Process Flag"
            SortExpression="PROCESS_FLAG" />
```

with

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>             
     <asp:Label ID="process_Flags" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PROCESS_FLAG").ToString()%>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>                    
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in your code behind, do something like this:

```
 protected void GridViewRowEventHandler(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           Label flag = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("process_Flags");
           DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("StatusDD");
            if (flag.Text == "A")
            {
                ddl.SelectedValue = "A";
            }
        //add more conditions here..

        }          
    }
```

this should get you a little further :)

Comment: The compiler says I do not have a reference to "e.Row".  What directive am I missing for that?

Comment: protected void GridViewRowEventHandler(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
did you make this method? if you place the code in there, you should have access to e.Row

Comment: Yup, sorry, that error was just a typo on my part.  It is saying that StatusDD does not exist in the current context now.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  I will try this out and post my findings.  :)

Comment: yeah well i dont know how you named your attributes and such, but my answer should guide you in the right direction. let me know if you have any problems

Comment: Worked like a charm.  This was the perfect solution to my question.  Thanks so much!